# Traffic obfuscation under targeted surveillance

Tags: network, obfuscation

When you are under targeted surveillance and all of your internet traffic is tapped (including parts where you exit from a VPN to the internet), is there any point in using traffic obfuscation? It won't matter if you use https, wireguard, openvpn ... the protocol could be the  the most rarely used in the world. It won't matter because the connection to the first hop/server can always be seen and you will always stick out. There is no point in hiding what protocol you use when connecting to the first server. Same probably for the next hops. Opinions?

Edit:

> what exactly you want to do

Make traffic look inconspicuous. In that case it would refer to for example make VPN traffic look like common https.

> who's your enemy

Nation state

> what kind of data you need to hide

As much as possible while at the same time keeping the connection usable for the average internet user.

Comment: If the observer is watching you obfuscate, there is no benefit in obfuscation.

Comment: Steganography might work in some specific cases but often has a low bandwidth. When someone is taking a close look at the traffic it probably also would stick out. Also what is "legitimate" data/'traffic/server in practice?  I edited the question.

Comment: By "legitimate" I meant that it's allowed by your enemy, it won't be noticed, it won't be suspicious. By the way, please mention the recipient whenever you leave a comment, like @reed, otherwise they won't get any notifications unless it's directly under one of their posts (I didn't get the notification of your comments, but you still got mine because it's under a post of yours).

Comment: @reed Suspicious depends a lot on the individual circumstances. If your standard traffic is some VPN protocol and you suddenly send all traffic to Facebook it might be less suspicious on a global scale but the local adversary will still notice. So it is pointless. The method used for obfuscation must also be perfect because otherwise you could stick out even more. To be usable you also need a way to make the transmitted data look legitimate (timing, size ...) and you need a trusted endpoint. Sure you could post a picture to facebook with some extra bits, but there you have your low bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, of course what is "suspicious" depends on the specific circumstances. Any changes in your traffic patterns or your online behavior (including any attempts at obfuscation) might be suspicious as well, it depends on what your enemy will consider "suspicious".

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a fairly good question that gets at the heart of how internet protocols work. This is gonna be a long answer; buckle up.

Let's separate this out into two parts:

1. protecting the *contents* of your traffic; that is, the plaintext content of the HTTP messages that you're sending and receiving.
2. protecting the *metadata* of your traffic; that's everything else including your IP address, the IP address of the server(s) you're communicating with, how much data you're sending and on what timing, etc.

**TL;DR:** For problem 1 the standard solution is TLS, and for problem 2 the standard solution is the Tor network.

---

## OSI Model Refresher

First, a quick refresher on the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). There's a ton of different protocols involved in your browser communicating with a server; from your network card jiggling the electrons on a copper wire or wifi connection in a very specific way, all the way up to putting the right unicode characters in the order to tell the server which html page or jpg you're trying to load. To keep our human sanity, we group protocols into one of the 7 "layers" of the OSI Model:

[image: OSI Model diagram]

---

## 1: Protecting message contents

Message contents is a Level 6 / 7 concern; you want to obscure the contents of that JPG or that HTTP POST.

Your question asks about a protocol to obfuscate your traffic so that it doesn't stick out. If you're talking about obfuscating the *contents* then we can actually do better: we can *encrypt* it. There is a super standard solution for this: **TLS** (formerly SSL), also known as **HTTPS** (for HTTP traffic). You also mention VPNs (usually the IPSEC protocol) which for the purposes of content encryption is very similar to TLS.

---

## 2: Protecting message metadata

If your question is not about contents, but also about metadata, this is a much harder problem.

Example: there's a quirk of video codecs such as H.264 that stream very little data when the scene is mostly static (very little change from one frame to the next) and a burst of data when the scene changes. There is some pretty cool research work showing that you can fingerprint the traffic bursts of a particular video and then pretty successfully tell which video someone is watching on youtube by observing the "shape" of their encrypted TLS traffic.

- [Silhouette: Identifying YouTube Video Flows from Encrypted Traffic](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3210445.3210448)
- [I Know What You Saw Last Minute—Encrypted HTTP Adaptive Video Streaming Title Classification](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7987775)

Your goal to obfuscate your traffic will also have the problem that in order for the internet infrastructure to deliver your packets to the right server (ie IP address), you need to label on your IP packets which address they are for. Direct clash between wanting to protect your metadata, and wanting your packets to reach their destination. This would require an obfuscation protocol at the OSI Level 3 layer.

Fortunately there is a standard solution for this too: **[the Tor network](https://www.torproject.org/)**! Though it takes a different approach than what you describe; instead of obfuscating your traffic by making it look "normal", they obfuscate your traffic by mixing it in with traffic from so many other people that it's nearly impossible to untangle which packets belong to who.

You say:

> It won't matter because the connection to the first hop/server can always be seen and you will always stick out. There is no point in hiding what protocol you use when connecting to the first server.

This certainly applies to Tor, but you "stick out" no more and no less than the other tens of millions of Tor users #strengthInNumbers

Comment: Just an observation on the *video streaming fingerprinting* . While it's an interesting academic study, it would not scale well. Their example database of 15 thousand is quite small. It's also specific to *streaming* vice *downloading* or browsing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only option that you have is a "**network cover channel**", some of them are easy to detect and other are really hard. I suggest you to read [Network Covert Channels: Design, Analysis, Detection, and Elimination](https://www.cerias.purdue.edu/assets/pdf/bibtex_archive/2006-53.pdf) and also there is a book called "Hiding in Plain Sight" from Eric cole that explain all the basics of the network covert channels, pros and cons, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under a *targeted surveillance* from an enemy that has access to your first *relay*, little can be done.

More exactly, it is trivial to hide the content of your exchanges (just use SSL protocols like HTTPS), and as it is now common it should not raise red flags. But it is much more difficult to hide your destination. Of course, you can use a VPN or even TOR, but this shows **explicitely** that you are willingly hiding your traffic. And that should be enough for all flags to turn red. If your enemy can only examine your traffic, and will not use *physical actions* until they have an evidence that what you do is illegal, this could be done. At least if you can trust them not to act differently as soon as they can *suspect* it. And even the old West European democracies sometimes use *special services*. So you must decide where using a *suspect* protocol is acceptable.

In fact the key here is whether you need [plausible deniability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability). If you do not, do not wory more and use TOR, or a good VPN (one you can trust to not give your data to your enemy). But if you do, TOR is not an option, and most VPN (anything besides a corporate VPN) are not either.

At the other end, and for few and small messages, you could hide them with steganography in genuine media files that you exchange on inoffensive sites. Provided you can avoid a too large increase in the exchanged volume, this is very hard to identify. But it is now very far from a *connection usable for the average internet user*.

Between both ends lies a *grey zone*. That means that if you can know what exactly is spied on, you can try to use other protocols or ways. If you expect the enemy to ignore some technics you can try to use them. You have here a balance between *security* and usability. But if the enemy is a nation state I would not go that way... An example of that grey zone, would be to use veracrypt containers with a hidden partition. It is simpler to use that steganography, but the unhidden partition must contain something that you could want to hide but more importantly which can be revealed to your enemy with no risk. It can be enough up to the [rubber hose](https://xkcd.com/538/) investigation methods.